# Limit OrbitControls horizontal rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I limit **horizontal** rotation on OrbitControls?

Inside the code I could see that it's possible to limit it vertically using `minPolarAngle` and `maxPolarAngle`. But I couldn't find a way to limit it horizontally.

--

Edit: I know that it OrbitControls doesn't rotate the Mesh but the Camera. I just want a solution to put horizontal limits on the camera.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EDIT: The ability to constrain camera movement both horizontally and vertically is a feature of [`OrbitControls`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js).

```js
// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
// Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

// How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
// If set, the interval [ min, max ] must be a sub-interval of [ - 2 PI, 2 PI ], with ( max - min < 2 PI )
this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians
```

three.js r.147

Comment: Can the min and max PolarAngles be (-)Infinity? I'd like it to keep rotating all around the object.

Comment: @defmech No. Use `TrackballControls`, instead.

Comment: Ah! Thanks… Always used orbit. Forgot there were others. :)