# OrbitControls - Can I enable/disable zooming dynamically?

Tags: three.js

I'm running Three.js r69 with the bundled OrbitControls.js. I have a simple scene with a couple of objects that are selectable. I'd like to be able to disable zooming while an object is selected and re-enable it once I've cleared the selection.

I'm working on a temporary solution, but it involves editing the OrbitControls.js code. This could make it really annoying to upgrade to a new version of Three.js, especially if OrbitControls is ever changed.

Is there currently a way to enable/disable certain features (like zooming, panning, or orbiting) on the fly, independently of each other?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Is simple:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

// to disable zoom
controls.enableZoom = false;

// to disable rotation
controls.enableRotate = false;

// to disable pan
controls.enablePan = false;
```

Comment: Yep. I figured this out minutes after I posted the question. Me.dumb += 5;

Comment: these `no` methods seem to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're editing the [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) you must have seen noZoom and noPan.

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827074/how-do-i-put-limits-on-orbitcontrol-three-js) shows how to constrain rotation.

Do these not meet your need?